# Omitting a verb from a second clause

Tags: grammar

Consider these two sentences:

- I rode my horse and you rode your bike.
- I rode my horse and you your bike.

I'm trying to find the grammatical explanation for why the second sentence is acceptable, even though its second clause (you your bike) has no verb.

Thanks!

Comment: It's called 'gapping' (or 'gapped coordination'). This occurs when the middle part (usually inc. the verb) of a non-initial coordinate is omitted but recoverable from the corresponding part of the first coordinate, thus "I rode my horse and you __ your bike", where gap is understood as "rode".

Comment: @Jim If you ever return, please mark an answer as accepted so the question doesn't keep popping up as "unanswered".

Comment: You might find two different answers to this question.  First, as others have said, 'gapping' in this way is common, and avoids a repetition of the verb 'rode'.  I am not sure, however, that I would ever utter that sentence.  It sounds peculiar, even though it is strictly correct.  I would prefer something like "Off we rode, me on my horse and you on your bike."

Comment: It's a very old-established form. There are a number of English folk songs, particularly ballads, which contain lines like "She mounted on her milk-white steed and he on the dapple grey". These songs often precede the invention of the bicycle by several centuries.

Answer (score 2):

@BillJ commented...

It's called *gapping* (or 'gapped coordination'). This occurs when the middle part (usually inc. the verb) of a non-initial coordinate is omitted but recoverable from the corresponding part of the first coordinate, thus "I rode my horse and you __ your bike", where gap is understood as "rode".